# Oracle® Database Express Edition. Create user ( Username retrieval failed )

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, database-administration

I've just installed Oracle® Database Express Edition, given the password admin to sys and sysadmin

Now I want to start to use it and I want to create user, so I connect using `sqlplus`

but I got this error

```
Enter user-name: sysadmin
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12631: Username retrieval failed
```

I also tried with sys user with the same result

Comment: Have you tried connecting as SYS?

Comment: even try to use as `sys as sysdba` from the command prompt.

Comment: When prompted to "Enter user-name", you should put `sys`. When prompted to "Enter password", you shoud put `sysadmin`. You used `sysadmin` as username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ORA-12638 is an Oracle database error, indicating that the SQL*Net client was unable to connect to the database.  In Windows, the Oracle Windows client attempt to use your current Windows domain credentials to authenticate you with the Oracle server. This could fail because the Windows box is not configured to support Windows authentication or because the credentials you use to login to your local machine are not sufficient to allow you to login to the server. There are several possible resolutions for the ORA-12638 error:

1:  In on Windows, bounce the server (stop and re-start) the Windows services for Oracle.

2:  The following direction was given, and once administered, was a successful resolution to ORA-12638:

*Please change the sqlnet.ora file in the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin directory. Change the following entry and the ORA-12638 error will disappear:*

> Change - SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
>
> To: - SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)